# What are the technical drawbacks our current Operating Systems have?

Tags: operating-system

Linux, Windows, OSX, any OS. What is the one thing all of them lack?
You have better control in Linux, it is secure. Windows, OSX is more user-friendly. OSX is also secure. 
But what do all of them don't have? Security wise or some other feature.

Comment: ...and your software development question is....?

Comment: Was my question not clear?

Comment: You mean your opinion poll and/or research request above?

Comment: Research request